# How do I determine expected harmonic frequencies and corresponding amplitudes in a case of synchronous machine?

Tags: motor, harmonics, fault

1)find harmonic frequencies which source in synchronous machine in a) fault, and b) fault-free operation conditions, in steady state mode.
2) and find how harmonics are depended on power factor, load etc.

There seem to be some literature with equations for finding harmonic frequencies sourced in synchronous machine, however I’m not able to find anything about expected amplitudes.

EDIT: It's for wound rotor synch machine, particularity 20MW Siemens mill drive

Comment: I believe that harmonics sourced in synchronous machines refers to flux harmonics and the resulting torque and current harmonics that are primarily caused by variations in the reluctance of the flux path with changes in rotor angle. If this motor is powered through a variable frequency drive (VFD) you may be more concerned with harmonics sourced from the VFD.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about wound-field synchronous machines, you probably need to look at older literature and text books. Recent research is more concerned with permanent magnet machines. Wound-field synchronous motors are generally only constructed in high power ratings above 2000 Hp (1.5 Mw) or so. Only about a half dozen manufacturers construct them. Smaller synchronous generators are constructed for engine-generator sets, but they are generally manufactured by or for engine-generator set manufacturers. It may be difficult to find design details for any wound-field machines.

For permanent-magnet machines, you should be able to find study results and data in more recent literature and even advanced design texts. You may need access to a pretty good engineering library.

It might be helpful to search for standards that might specify allowable harmonic amplitudes.

I have an old text that has data for a 2500 kVA, 32 pole generator. It seems to show about 2% for the 3rd, 9% for the 5th and 3% for the 7th.

Comment: I would question the "high power rating" cutoff being around 1.5MVA for wound rotor Sync machines. Aerospace use wound rotor ,rotating diode sync machines and these are around 250kVA

Comment: I wasn't intending to imply that there is a definite cutoff point, only that they are not sold in large numbers to a large pool of customers, so there is a not lot of widely published and easily obtainable technical information about them.